# Rails meta_search greater and less conditions in one combobox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, meta-search

I have a model `Phone` with `checked_by` field; if this field is equal to 1, then we know this phone  is **unchecked**, else(>1) - **checked**. On admin side I can review a list of `Phones` and I need to create a filter using meta_search to review:

- All Phones
- Checked
- Unchecked

I can see `checked_by_greater_than`, or `checked_by_less_than` methods in meta_search, but how to combine those methods in a single select box?

Thanks in any advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a scope and a made-up field.

The scope:

```
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :checked, lambda { |value| 
      !value.zero? ? checked_by_greater_than(1) : where(:checked_by => 1)
  }

end
```

Then add a select-box with three values, returning `[nil, 0, 1]` as values, and in your controller use that parameter to apply the new scope.

```
class PhonesController < ApplicationController

  def index

    # ...
    @phones ||= Phone.scoped
    checked_select_value = params.delete("checked_select") # here use the name of your form field
    if checked_select_value.present?
      @phones = @phones.checked(checked_select_value.to_i)
    end
    # now apply the rest of your meta-search things to the @phones

    #
  end
end
```

Comment: can't apply scopes to `Phone.all`, but I got the point, thank you

Comment: By the way, you can use `Phone.scoped` and it will behave as `Phone.all` in addition of being able to apply scopes on it.